# Получение остатка деления длинных чисел выдает исключение

Tags: c++

Недавно просил помощи здесь по написанию программы, которая получала бы остаток от деления двух длинных чисел. Написал программу, но вот проблема, когда дело доходит до сдвига вправо (деление реализовано столбиком), то вызывает исключение "0x00052DEB". Погуглил, сказано, что так нельзя так обращаться к массиву, почему так и не понял. Исключение возникает, когда доходит до функции SdvigRIght() (описана в начале программы в структуре BigInt. Помогите, пожалуйста, остались последние штрихи, а что это за исключение и как его исправить, идей вообще нет. Можно ли как-то реализовать без обработки исключений?

Алгоритм взятия остатка брал с сайта http://cppalgo.blogspot.ru/2010/05/blog-post.html

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int max_len = 10000; //максимальное количество цифр в числе
int osn = 10; //осование системы счисления

struct BigInt
{
    int amount;  //количество цифр в числе
    int digits[max_len]; //массив цифр в обратном порядке

    void Input()
    {
        memset(digits, 0, sizeof(digits)); //заполняем нулями digits
        string mainNumber;
        cin >> mainNumber;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = mainNumber.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            digits[index++] = mainNumber[i] - '0';
        }
        amount = mainNumber.size();
    }

    void output()
    {
        for (int i = amount - 1;i >= 0;i--)
            cout << digits[i];
    }

    void SdvigRight()
    {
        for (int i = amount;i >= 1;i--)
            digits[i] = digits[i - 1];
        if (digits[amount])
            amount++;
    }
};

BigInt operator - (const BigInt &delitel, const int &n)
{
    BigInt res = delitel;
    int index = 0;
    res.digits[0] -= n;
    while (res.digits[index] < 0)
    {
        res.digits[index + 1]--;
        res.digits[index++] += osn;
    }
    if (res.amount && !res.digits[res.amount - 1])
        res.amount--;
    return res;
}

BigInt operator / (const BigInt &mainNumber, const int rezhuDelitel)
{
    BigInt res;
    res.amount = mainNumber.amount;
    int ost = 0;
    for (int i = res.amount - 1;i >= 0;i--)
    {
        int cur = ost * osn + mainNumber.digits[i];
        res.digits[i] = cur / rezhuDelitel;
        ost = cur % rezhuDelitel;
    }
    if (!res.digits[res.amount - 1] && res.amount != 1)
        res.amount--;
    return res;
}


bool operator <= (const BigInt &cur, const BigInt &curValue)
{
    if (cur.amount != curValue.amount)
        return cur.amount<curValue.amount;

    for (int i = cur.amount - 1;i >= 0;i--)
    {
        if (cur.digits[i] != curValue.digits[i])
            return cur.digits[i] < curValue.digits[i];
    }
    return true;
}

BigInt operator * (const BigInt &delitel, const int &x)
{
    BigInt res;
    res.amount = delitel.amount;

    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<res.amount | r;i++)
    {
        res.digits[i] = delitel.digits[i] * x + r;
        r = res.digits[i] / osn;
        res.digits[i] -= r*osn;
    }
    if (res.digits[res.amount])
        res.amount++;

    return res;
}



BigInt operator - (const BigInt &curValue, const BigInt &delitel)
{
    BigInt res = curValue;
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<res.amount;i++)
    {
        res.digits[i] -= delitel.digits[i] + r;
        if (res.digits[i]<0)
        {
            res.digits[i] += osn;
            r = 1;
        }
        else
            r = 0;
    }
    if (!res.digits[res.amount - 1] && res.amount != 1)
        res.amount--;
    return res;
}


BigInt operator % (const BigInt &mainNumber, const BigInt &delitel)
{
    BigInt res;
    BigInt curValue;
    for (int i = mainNumber.amount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        curValue.SdvigRight(); // * osn
        curValue.digits[0] = mainNumber.digits[i];
        // подбираем максимальное число x, такое что b * x <= curValue
        int x = 0;
        int l = 0, r = osn;
        while (l <= r)
        {
            int m = (l + r) >> 1;
            BigInt cur = delitel * m;
            if (cur <= curValue)
            {
                x = m;
                l = m + 1;
            }
            else
                r = m - 1;
        }
        res.digits[i] = x;
        curValue = curValue - delitel * x;
    }
    return curValue;
}

int main()
{
    BigInt mainNumber;
    mainNumber.Input();
    cout << endl;
    BigInt delitel = mainNumber - 1;
    delitel.output();

    cout << endl;
    BigInt ostatok = mainNumber % delitel;
    ostatok.output();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Отладчик - ваш друг. Чем гадать что и как - посмотрите в отладчике.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов том-то и дело, что прошел уже отладчиком. Знаю ,где ошибка. но не знаю почему

Comment: И где ошибка? Укажите конкретную строку.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов if (digits[amount])
   amount++; //35 - 40 строки

Comment: Ошибка возникает на одной конкретной строке, допустим это приведенная строка. Чему в этот момент равно значение amount?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Да, вы правы, amount равно -858993460. Но почему он вылетает за границу, я посмотрел, вроде нигде не должен выехать за нее

Comment: Меня, конечно, закидают ссаными тряпками, но: signed для индекса, который в принципе не может быть отрицательным - IMHO не лучшая идея. Далее: смотрите в сторону инициализации amount, судя по 0xCCCCC... он не инициализирован. Дальше уже смотрите по стеку вызовов откуда оно так вышло.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я вас не понял. Можете пояснить, что не так?